# Wget, URLs, Python and Mysql encoding

Tags: python, character-encoding, wget, urlencode

I am using wget to download recursively an entire website. The command I use is:

```
wget
  -rH   
  --level=inf
  --adjust-extension
  --no-check-certificate
  --restrict-file-names=unix
  --execute robots=off
```

The output, is saved on a Ubuntu 20 machine.

Using python3, I get the URLs from the file path with the following code:

```
for root, _, f_names in os.walk(target_path, topdown=False):
    for current_file in f_names:
        file_url: tmp_file_url.encode("utf-8", 'backslashreplace').decode("utf-8"), #Encode URL to escape "weird" characters
```

And finally I insert that URL to a MySQL database with utf8mb4 collation.

In one case, I cannot find the correct way to encode/escape the following URL:

Encoded version:

```
**DOMAIN**/happy-hallowine-\u200d♀️\u200d♂️-tomorrow-thursday-we-have-new-bites-on-the-menu-such-as-grilled-vegg/index.html
```

Decoded version (http://www.asiteaboutnothing.net/c_decode-url.html):

`**DOMAIN**%2Fhappy-hallowine-%F0%9F%A7%9B%F0%9F%8F%BD%2Fu200d%E2%99%80%EF%B8%8F%F0%9F%8D%B7%F0%9F%A7%9B%F0%9F%8F%BD%2Fu200d%E2%99%82%EF%B8%8F-tomorrow-thursday-we-have-new-bites-on-the-menu-such-as-grilled-vegg%2Findex.h`tml

Questions:

- How can I reliably make sure that WGET use "the right" encoding?
- Is there any trick that can be done in python to manage this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questionable part of your string (-‍♀️‍♂️-) contains literally `\\u200d` i.e. *escaped* character `\u200d` (U+200D,  *Zero Width Joiner*). A solution could be as simple as follows:

```
from urllib.parse import quote, unquote

temp_str = r'-\u200d♀️\u200d♂️-'
print( 'temp_str', temp_str)
print( 'temp_url', quote(temp_str))

good_str = temp_str.encode( 'raw_unicode_escape').decode( 'unicode_escape')
print( 'good_str', good_str)
print( 'good_url', quote(good_str))
```

**Result:** `.\SO\70881227.py`

```
temp_str -\u200d♀️\u200d♂️-
temp_url -%F0%9F%A7%9B%F0%9F%8F%BD%5Cu200d%E2%99%80%EF%B8%8F%F0%9F%8D%B7%F0%9F%A7%9B%F0%9F%8F%BD%5Cu200d%E2%99%82%EF%B8%8F-
good_str -‍♀️‍♂️-
good_url -%F0%9F%A7%9B%F0%9F%8F%BD%E2%80%8D%E2%99%80%EF%B8%8F%F0%9F%8D%B7%F0%9F%A7%9B%F0%9F%8F%BD%E2%80%8D%E2%99%82%EF%B8%8F-
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- [Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) `unicode_escape` and `raw_unicode_escape`
- [Emoji Sequences](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-sequence/) (in particular, [man/woman Vampire](https://emojipedia.org/search/?q=VAMPIRE))

**Full character list** of the questionable part of your string (-‍♀️‍♂️-):

- `-` (U+002D,  *Hyphen-Minus*)
- (U+1F9DB, *VAMPIRE (0xd83e,0xdddb)*)
- (U+1F3FD, *EMOJI MODIFIER FITZPATRICK TYPE-4 (0xd83c,0xdffd)*)
- `‍` (U+200D,  *Zero Width Joiner*)
- `♀` (U+2640,  *Female Sign*)
- `️` (U+FE0F,  *Variation Selector-16*)
- (U+1F377, *WINE GLASS (0xd83c,0xdf77)*)
- (U+1F9DB, *VAMPIRE (0xd83e,0xdddb)*)
- (U+1F3FD, *EMOJI MODIFIER FITZPATRICK TYPE-4 (0xd83c,0xdffd)*)
- `‍` (U+200D,  *Zero Width Joiner*)
- `♂` (U+2642,  *Male Sign*)
- `️` (U+FE0F,  *Variation Selector-16*)
- `-` (U+002D,  *Hyphen-Minus*)